# Number of paths in matrix

Tags: c++, recursion, matrix, path

My task is to write a function that returns the number of valid paths in a matrix from top left to bottom right. The matrix consists of bools, where 1 represents a wall and 0 a free cell. So the task is to find the number of paths through the free cells. I wrote some code but it somehow doesn‘t work. I‘m a beginner in programming. I have to use recursion and have use .at() instead of [].

```
#include "valid_path.h" 
#include <vector> 


void path_counter (unsigned int n, unsigned int m, unsigned int i, 
unsigned int j, int &num, std::vector<std::vector<bool>> mat); 

// PRE: -
// POST: Returns the number of valid paths through mat starting at (0, 0).
//       Valid paths can only move right or down.  
int valid_paths (const std::vector<std::vector<bool>> &mat) { 
  const unsigned int n = mat.size();
  const unsigned int m = mat.at(0).size();
  
  int num_of_paths = 0; 
  int i = 0; 
  int j = 0; 
  
  path_counter(n, m, i, j, num_of_paths, mat); 
  
  return num_of_paths; 
} 


void path_counter (unsigned int n, unsigned int m, unsigned int i, 
unsigned int j, int &num, std::vector<std::vector<bool>> mat) { 
  
  if(i>n-1) {num+=0; } 
  
  while (i<=n-1 && j<=m-1) { 
    if ((i==n-2 && j==m-1) || (i==n-1 && j==m-2)) { 
      if (mat.at(i).at(j) == 0) {num+=1; } 
    } 
    else if (mat.at(i+1).at(j) == 0 && mat.at(i).at(j+1) == 0) { 
      path_counter(n, m, i+1, j, num, mat); 
      path_counter(n, m, i, j+1, num, mat); 
    } 
    else if (mat.at(i+1).at(j) == 1 && mat.at(i).at(j+1) == 0) { 
      path_counter(n, m, i, j+1, num, mat); 
    } 
    else if (mat.at(i+1).at(j) == 0 && mat.at(i).at(j+1) == 1) { 
      path_counter(n, m, i+1, j, num, mat); 
    } 
    else if (mat.at(i+1).at(j) == 1 && mat.at(i).at(j+1) == 1) { 
      num+=0; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: I get cpu_clock_timeout and std::out_of_range errors.

Answer (score 1):

I would ditch the recursion and just accumulate the path lengths in a matrix `counts` the same size as `mat`:

```
int getCount(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& counts, int i, int j) {
  if (i < 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (j < 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  return counts[i][j];
}

int valid_paths(const std::vector<std::vector<bool>> &mat) {
  int m = mat.size();
  int n = mat[0].size();
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> counts;

  // Initialization
  for (const auto& row: mat) {
    counts.push_back(std::vector<int>(row.size(), 0));
  }
  if (mat[0][0]) {
    counts[0][0] = 1;
  }

  int k = (m-1) + (n-1) + 1;
  for (int i = 1; i < k; i++) {
    int row = std::min(i, m-1);
    int col = i - row;
    while (row >= 0 && col < n) {
      counts[row][col] = mat[row][col]?
        getCount(counts, row-1, col) + getCount(counts, row, col-1) : 0;
      row--;
      col++;
    }
  }
  return counts[m-1][n-1];
}
```